# Find all occurrence of Int32 value assigned to Int64 property. parameter or field

Tags: c#, casting, long-integer

I am in process of converting some DB fields from Int32 to Int64. My application needs to reflect that too. But in a huge code base, I am trying to find all the occurrence where an int is assigned to my (now) properties

```
long amount = resopnse.Value; /*Int32*/
```

While assignments like this don't generate any compilation error, I would like to go thru the entire chain and convert all the int values to long, which are being assigned to my (now) long fields.

Is there a way to find all such assignments of int to a long member?

Comment: INT to long have a implicit cast and so not sure why you are bothering about? If needed you can probably replace all int variables to long.

Comment: Could you use `ulong` instead of `long` to spot all the places first? (C# does not convert `int` to `ulong` implicitly.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ReSharper for visual studio to find them all (They have a trial version I bet) https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/
[image]

Click on object browser of a int32 and find all usages. Tons of other cool stuff resharper can do if you need help figuring it out let me know.